# My cursor won't show up on Windows 8.1 when i use touch screen

Tags: windows-8, mouse, touchscreen

I have Windows 8.1 with custom cursors and my normal mouse cursor (not the link select, move, or any other one) will disappear when i use touch screen (normal so far) but wont come back until i go to my cursor settings and hit ok without changing anything. Does anyone know my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your mouse may have turned itself off, when you go into your mouse setting click on the touch pad option, then click to change the settings. It should say on, turn it off, save, then turn it back on, it should be fine

Comment: I'm on Windows 10 now, and it works just fine. Probably just a Windows 8/8.1 thing.